# How to assist type inference in polymorphism?

Tags: scala

**Old title: How do you show or assert that a List is TraversableOnce?**

I have been trying to devise a trait for some classes. In the trait, I have tried either of:

```
  //First try:
  def addData[A <: Any](newTweets: => List[A]): Unit
  //Second try
  def addData[A <: List[Any]](newTweets: => A): Unit
  //Third try
  def addData[A <: List[Any]](newTweets: => A): Unit
```

I have a couple of different implementations, e.g.:

```
  def addData[Future[JsValue]](newData: => List[Future[JsValue]]): Unit = {
    dataList ++= newData
  }
```

or

```
  def addData[Tweet](newTweets: => List[Tweet]): Unit = {
    tweetsList ++= newTweets
    tweetsList = tweetsList.sortWith(
      (a,b) => a.created_at.getTime < b.created_at.getTime
    )
```

I get errors both in IntelliJ and by the compiler asserting something like the following:

```
JsonPublisher.scala:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]
 required: scala.collection.TraversableOnce[scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]
    dataList ++= newData
```

The part I'm most confused about is that I believe List should implement TransversableOnce. Also, this worked fine prior to making the classes extend from a custom trait. The only difference was that I didn't parameterize the method's type in the class, e.g., I had `def addData(...` instead of `addData[Tweet](...`. But if I leave I don't change the functional form to be parameterized when extending from a trait, I get a complaint that I haven't implemented `addData`.

I'd welcome both new approachs and hints as to why this error is occurring (since List should be TransversableOnce).

**EDIT**:

After forgetting lists and making everything `TransversableOnce`, I'm still getting a likely equivalent error but possibly more illuminating (just not to me ):

```
[ant:scalac] /home/brandon/CommVis/jvm-scala/tweet-serve/src/main/scala/edu/cornell/comm/twitter/JsonPublisher.scala:23: error: type mismatch;
[ant:scalac]  found   : TraversableOnce[Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]
[ant:scalac]  required: scala.collection.TraversableOnce[scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]
[ant:scalac]     dataList ++= newData
[ant:scalac]                  ^
[ant:scalac] /home/brandon/CommVis/jvm-scala/tweet-serve/src/main/scala/edu/cornell/comm/twitter/TweetPublisher.scala:38: error: type mismatch;
[ant:scalac]  found   : scala.collection.TraversableOnce[Tweet]
[ant:scalac]  required: scala.collection.TraversableOnce[edu.cornell.comm.twitter.Tweet]
[ant:scalac]     tweetsList ++= newTweets
```

I'll also include more complete code:

**Trait**

```
package edu.cornell.comm.api

import scala.collection.{TraversableOnce}
import scala.collection.mutable.{MutableList, Publisher}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import edu.cornell.comm.twitter.types.Tweet
import scala.collection.mutable.{Publisher}

trait MicroBlogPublisher[T] extends Publisher[Future[String]] {

  def addData[T](newTweets: => TraversableOnce[T]): Unit

}
```

**Implementation One**

```
package edu.cornell.comm.twitter

import edu.cornell.comm.api.MicroBlogPublisher
import edu.cornell.comm.twitter.types.IOHelpers._
import edu.cornell.comm.twitter.types._
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}
import scala.collection.mutable.{MutableList, Publisher}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._

class JsonPublisher extends MicroBlogPublisher[Future[JsValue]] {

  protected var dataList: MutableList[Future[JsValue]] = MutableList.empty

  def addData[Future[JsValue]](newData: => TraversableOnce[Future[JsValue]]): Unit = {
    dataList ++= newData
  }


}
```

**Implementation Two**

```
package edu.cornell.comm.twitter

import edu.cornell.comm.api.MicroBlogPublisher
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import scala.collection.{TraversableOnce}
import scala.collection.mutable.{MutableList, Publisher}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import edu.cornell.comm.twitter.types._
import IOHelpers._

class TweetPublisher extends MicroBlogPublisher[Tweet] {


  protected var tweetsList: MutableList[Tweet] = MutableList.empty


  def addData[Tweet](newTweets: => TraversableOnce[Tweet]): Unit = {
    tweetsList ++= newTweets
    tweetsList = tweetsList.sortWith(
      (a,b) => a.created_at.getTime < b.created_at.getTime
    )
  }


}
```

Comment: I think this may have to do with Scala's "rank-1 polymorphism", though I'm still not immediately sure what the solution would be for dealing with this: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html

Comment: can you please elaborate on your code: how and where `dataList` is defined, how two of your traits extend each other (including type params), override `dataList` and `addData` method.

Comment: I didn't include dataList in the trait; I've now updated (and changed the title), see after edit. Maybe I should change the title again later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite funny case you've got.

Here is the correct code:

```
trait MicroBlogPublisher[T] extends Publisher[Future[String]] {
  def addData(newTweets: => TraversableOnce[T]): Unit
}

class JsonPublisher extends MicroBlogPublisher[Future[JsValue]] {
  protected var dataList: MutableList[Future[JsValue]] = MutableList.empty
  override def addData(newData: => TraversableOnce[Future[JsValue]]): Unit = {
    dataList ++= newData
  }
}
```

The problem was that method `addData` declared own generic type `T` which was completely unrelated to the type parameter `T` of the trait. Now the funny part, in concrete implementation, for example `JsonPublisher`, the declaration `def addData[Future[JsValue]](...` actually declared two generic type parameters with confusing names `Future`  and `JsValue`. But actually this declaration was the synonym of `def addData[P[Q]](...`.

Now how you could have avoid this mistake.

For me Idea shows warning for the declaration of `def addData[T]` in `MicroBlogPublisher` saying: "Suspicious shadowing of the type parameter T". It should have pointed you that `T` is now what it appears to be. Next thing, when you are overriding methods, don't forget `override` keyword. When something is wrong with the signature of overriding method you'll be advised of it.

Comment: I can see why you say it is funny now ... definitely a special beginner mistake. Interestingly I did not have that warning in IDEA, though maybe when I looked my code was in a slightly different state. I had `Type mismatch, expected: TraversableOnce[Tweet], actual: TraversableOnce[Tweet]` ... a fun error that I've had more than once for other reasons.